# Updating a state variable inside of a react function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm using the State Hook to update a Throttle setting for a robot based on keyboard commands (W,A,S,D). I have a maxThrottle state variable that ensures that the robot doesn't go too fast. However, I am using a slider to adjust the maxThrottle command. When you press the W key (forward) you should get the current maxThrottle['forward'] value assigned to the throttleCommand variable.  However, every time the handleKey function runs, I just get throttleCommand['forward'] set to the initial value of 30, even if I have changed maxThrottle (using setMaxThrottle) to a higher number like 80.

```
function App(){

//state hooks
    const [ throttleCommand, setThrottleCommand ] = useState({ forward: 0, turn: 0 });
    const [ maxThrottle, setMaxThrottle ] = useState({ forward: 30, turn: 15 });

useEffect(
        () => {
            sendThrottle(throttleCommand);
        },
        [ throttleCommand ]
    );

    const handleKey = (e) => {
        switch (e.code) {
            case 'KeyW':
                setThrottleCommand({ ...throttleCommand, forward: maxThrottle.forward });
                break;
            case 'KeyS':
                //THIS SHOULD TURN IT OFFF
                setThrottleCommand({ forward: 0, turn: 0 });
                break;
            case 'KeyA':
                //turn left
                setThrottleCommand({ ...throttleCommand, turn: -maxThrottle.turn });
                break;
            case 'KeyD':
                setThrottleCommand({ ...throttleCommand, turn: maxThrottle.turn });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };


    const sendThrottle = () => {
        //here I test the throttleCommand
        console.log('sending command', throttleCommand);
        axios.get(`/throttle/${throttleCommand.forward}/${throttleCommand.turn}`).then((res) =>    {
            setThrottleData(res.data);
        });
    };

....

}
```

I have verified that I successfully update maxThrottle to {forward:80,turn:20} but when I press the W key, the throttleCommand is logged as {forward:30, turn:0}.  I am expecting to see {forward:80,turn:0} assigned to throttleCommand.

Is there something wrong with using a state variable inside the handleKey function? Why am I always getting the initial value of maxThrottle assigned to throttleCommand?

Comment: Where do you set the 'handleKey' callback? While I don't see it in the code, my suspicion is that the callback is set to the 'handleKey' function at the start, and as updates occur to the state, the callback function itself isn't being updated, and still have the scope of the original state.

Comment: In the `KeyW` case, you are having `forward` key already, so instead of spreading the object, you can directly add `turn` as `turn: throttleCommand.turn` and remove the object spread.

Answer (score 0):

Michael Bauer! Thanks for the fix. You are 100% correct. Code now works. here is the change:

incorrect keydown listener:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown',handleKey);
    }, []);
```

**SOLVED / CORRECT keydown listener**

```
    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            handleKey(e);
        });
    }, []);
```

Lesson learned - use arrow functions inside of useEffect so that the callback function updates!